# passing a lambda expression as call back function at the very same lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

Here is my code

```
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);

private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    ...
   _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
}
```

i was trying to shorten that to a lambda expression 
to be

```
_serverSocket.BeginAccept(AR => {

}, null);
```

and i was thinking if there is a way to just pass a lambda expression as delegate method to be called on event , i'm talking about general purposes of how to call the same lambda expression from inside the very same expression (kinda like recursion), is it even possible

and at this particular case, is there a way around that, not to use a loop that will freeze the application and still use lambda as accept call back that still call begin accept from inside the lambda expression

Comment: Here's an awaitable socket http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
AsyncCallback asyncCallback = null;
asyncCallback = ar =>
{
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(asyncCallback, null);
};
_serverSocket.BeginAccept(asyncCallback, null);
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  It looks like it's recursive, the delegate calls the delegate...